# is there a way to provide search annotation in minizinc predicate?

Tags: minizinc

I am wondering if I could provide search order in a minizinc predicate. For instance I have code like this

```
predicate numbers_falling_within_range (var int:a, var int:b)=
      let {
         var 213233..4535553: num;
       } in 
       (a+b<num*64+64) /\ (a+b>num*64);  %% pick a and b such that their sum fall within a range
```

Here I would prefer when it executes the predicate, it solves for `num` first, before  `a` or `b`. Is there a way to do it? I am looking for something similar to solve order annotation we provide at end of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where you can devise a search strategy is in you solve item, but you might also ask: "Can I devise a search strategy over (to a predicate) local variables?"

Since MiniZinc is a scoped language, you can't really access these variables outside of the predicate, but you can elevate them to the global scope:

```
int num_num = ???;
array[1..num_num] of var 213233..4535553: nums;
predicate numbers_falling_within_range (var int: a, var int: b, var int: num) =
  (a+b<num*64+64) /\ (a+b>num*64);

% a call to the predicate
constraint numbers_falling_within_range(x, y, nums[1]);

solve ::int_search(nums, input_order, indomain_min) minimize cost;
```

Note that this kind of approach is only possible if the can (over-)estimate the number of calls to the predicate and give each call a different (now global) variable. Unless your predicate is recursive, this should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: I see. This idea of bringing out the local variable is good. I will try out.  By the way i want to ask is it feasible to provide such annotation within scope of predicate from minizinc language perspective? some type  of "solve before" type of hints?

Comment: Because of the nature of declarative languages, approaches where you iteratively   build things are often not possible. It is often not hard to rephrase these approaches into something that add things to the global state, which is possible. So to answer your question directly in MiniZinc there is currently no such functionality like the one you are describing.